# How can I tell how many times these nested statements will execute?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have the following pseudocode:

```
SelectionSort(A)
    n = A.length
    for j=1 to n-1
        smallest = j
        for i=(j+1) to n
            if A[i] < A[smallest]
                smallest = i
        exchange A[j] with A[smallest]
```

I think that the first for-loop test will execute n times, and the nested for-loop will execute 1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2 times (please correct me if i'm wrong). But I don't understand how I can tell how many times the nested if-statement will execute? Is it 1/2 * n(n+1)/2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer for-loop would run for `n` times. But, it also holds an inner for-loop which is dependent on the vale of j.

> I think that the first for-loop test will execute n times, and the
>   nested for-loop will execute 1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2 times.

The inner for-loop will run (n-1)+(n-2)+...+1 times based on all the iterations of outer for-loop. So, the net iteration of the loop-statements combinedly would be (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1 = (n-1)*n/2 = (n<sup>2</sup>-n)/2 times.

> But I don't understand how I can tell how many times the nested
>   if-statement will execute? Is it 1/2 * n(n+1)/2 ?

As the inner-if statement is dependent on the array elements, it is not possible to directly ascertain exactly how many times it will run.

But, it is for sure that in the worst-case condition,as it is located in the inner for-loop, the maximum number of possible execution(in the worst case) of the if-statement will be (n<sup>2</sup>-n)/2 times.

> So, the worst-case complexity of execution of if-statement is
>   ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)***

Comment: But won't the inner loop run n times for the first iteration of the outer loop, when j = 1?

Comment: @AliMustafa-No, as i's value will be set to 2(because i=j+1), which means it will iterate the loop from i=2 to i=n, means a total of n-1 iterations.

Comment: Ok, can you see if I got this right: outer for-loop header executes n times and outer for-loop's body executes n-1 times? inner for-loop header executes n times and inner for-loop's body executes n-1 times? When j=1

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The header of for-loop executes one time more than their body because the test-condition is checked at each entry which turns false in the case when condition is not met and hence,loop-terminates. And, I'd suggest you to not think much about loop-headers, and only think about number of executions of loop-body. This will help you in the longer run. Good Luck. :) @AliMustafa

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop shall run from 1 to n-1, hence n-1 times.
The inner loop shall run from j+1 to n times. This means that when j is 1, it will run from 2 to n times (n-1 times) and when j is n-1, it will run from n to n times (1 time).

Hence the inner loop shall run (n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1) times = n(n-1)/2 times.

The if statement shall execute the same number of times as the inner loop does. Ofcourse the conditional statments shall depend on the result of if conditional.